# Let $x_n$ be sequence converging to $0$ . What can you say about sequence $(x_n)^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_n$ be sequence converging to $0$ .What can you say about sequence $(x_n)^{n}$

**ATTEMPT**

$|x_n|<\epsilon^{1/n}$ for all $n \geq$ m
implies $ |x_n|^{n} < \epsilon $. Thus  new sequence is converges to $0$.  But problem is epsilon is dependent upon $n$ ,in my first step. How should I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: Hint: you know that $|x_n|<\frac{1}{2}$ for sufficiently large $n$. Can you compare $|x_n^n|$ to $|x_n|$?

Comment: @Wojowu $(x_n)^{n} < x <\epsilon $

Comment: A lot of people put a space *before* the period (or question mark) and no space after.  Like "Hello .How are you?"  This post, for example, made this mistake in every single case (I fixed most of them, left the one in the title).  So it's not just a typo, people seem to think that is correct and do it every time.  Why do people do this?  Is that normal in some other language?

Comment: @K.Dutta I hate to tell you, but it definitely decreases readability - at least for an English speaker.  Do other people agree that punctuating wrong actually increases readability?

Comment: @K.Dutta No, I'm saying there should be a space between the punctuation mark and the beginning of the next sentence.  And there should not be a space between it and the last character of the previous sentence.

Comment: @GregoryGrant ok i will see to it next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If a real number $x$ is between $0$ and $1$ then $0<x^n<x$ for $n\ge 2$. Can you make a sandwich with this?

Answer (score 0):

If $|x_n| < 1$,
as has to happen eventually,
then
$|x^n|^n$ is much smaller than
$|x_n|$,
so it certainly converges to zero.

More challenging:
Find sequences
$x_n \to 0$
and $y_n \to 0$
such that
$x_n^{1/n}$
converges and
$y_n^{1/n}$
diverges.